# Switching from SQL Server Express to SDF database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, connection-string, sdf

I've created an mvc project with following connection string (which is a default):

```
<add name="TestDb" 
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I would like to switch from SQL Server Express to one of the file databases, so that I can store my db in same repository. How can I do this (steps/connection string) ?

I'm using MVC code first approach. Thank you.

Comment: `.sdf` = SQL Server Compact Edition - you need to install the necessary runtime binaries and tooling; `.mdf` = SQL Server full version (Express, Web, Standard, Enterprise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install the the EntityFramework.SQLServerCompact NuGet package.
2. Change your connection string to this:

   <add name="TestDb"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"
   connectionString=
   "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.sdf" />

With Code First, you typically use the context class name as your connection string name.

Comment: thank you. Even with this Connection String I get connected to SQLEXPRESS. How can I remove this default connection to test out your connection string please ?

Comment: What is the name of your code first context class?  Did you change the name of the connection string to match that?  Your web.config file probably specifies SQL Express as the default connection when there is no connection string, and code first isn't finding the connection string because the name doesn't match the context class name.